# Chi square test for 2d continuous data?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a 2 dimensiontal data, and I fit a model for it. I want to use `chi square` to test the `goodness of fit`.

The empirical distribution(KDE) of the data(left), and my model(right):
[image]

But I only find info about doing it for `1d` or `2 way table`(for categorical data).

Is it possible to do `chi square` for `2d` data? i.e. the `frequency` is dependent on `(x,y)`, not just `x`.

Or if there is other good approach for testing the goodness of it? I've tried `R square`, and looking for some other indicators.

Comment: I think you need to look under 'goodness of fit tests'. Chi-squared GOF tests are for categorical data. For one-dimensional continuous data, versions of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov GOF test are commonly used. Prowling around just now on the Internet, I found references to a two-dimensional K-S test.

Comment: @BruceET, Chi-square can be used for continuous data, as long as I `binned` the data. And thanks, I'm also reading `2d K-S test` right now.

Comment: Right. In my experience the GOF results from binned data are heavily dependent on the binning.

Comment: My guess is that you may try two-dimensional binning for similar chi-square test.

Comment: @BGM, yes, and that's what I'm trying to ask. But I really didn't find too many info about `2d chi-square` test. I'm now trying to use `2d K-S`, looks like a popular choice.