# Goodness of fit test for bivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a dataset which is `x-y` distributed(left, a `kernel density estimation`), and I fitted a model for it(right).

How can I test the `goodness of fit` for the model I fitted?

[image]

What I've done:

After searching for a while, I found this http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2407
. And it seems still a big problem to be solved? I read http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715297000205, but the result seems quite un-sensitive.

I'm not a stat/math majored students, so I'm posting here to see what are the popular approaches for doing the `gof test`?

Note:

This comes from my previous question([Chi square test for 2d continuous data?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585244/chi-square-test-for-2d-continuous-data)), I re-phrased it again, since this may be clearer than the previous one.